# Error message by shell on running addr2line pragmatically on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, c, linux, shell

I have the following code :

```
        char command[256];
        sprintf(command,"addr2line %p -e xcep_app", trace[i]); 

        addr2lineWriter = popen(command, "r");
        if (addr2lineWriter == NULL) 
            flag = false;

        if (flag == true) //execute parsing the output only if the command ran in the first place
        {
            while (fgets(addr2line_output, sizeof(addr2line_output)-1, addr2lineWriter) != NULL) 
            {
                std::string addr2line_output_(addr2line_output);
                complete_backtrace_.push_back(addr2line_output_);
            }
            pclose(addr2lineWriter);
        }
```

Everything works fine, but I always get the following message : 
`sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")` 
Why is it coming and how to stop it. also, what does it mean  ? 
I have the gnome terminal installed.

Comment: How about providing some debug info? What is `command` after `sprintf`?

Comment: @kirelagin command is simply a character array.

Comment: Wow, that was obvious!

Comment: I know.I think I failed to understand your question.

Comment: I just want to be sure, that resulting `command` looks reasonable.

Comment: its ok. the addr2line execcutes smoothly as weell. the issue is just that eror message. thats all.

Comment: Oh, that was my next question. So, this command just appears on the terminal? It's not what you read from `addr2lineWriter`? What you read from `addr2lineWriter` is fine?

Comment: What are the contents of `command`?  How is `trace` declared and populated?  Please see http://sscce.org to learn how to ask questions that provide the right amount of information for us to help you.

Comment: I am pretty sure `trace[i]` is NULL, and causing this behavior. But, I don't know which shell is being used. I can't reproduce the same message that you are reporting.

Comment: @jxh `ash -c 'addr2line (null) -e something'` reproduces it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a guess based on the error message. `trace[i]` is NULL, so the command generated is:

```
addr2line (nil) -e xcep_app
```

And so the shell that is invoked to execute the command complains about the parentheses. @WumpusQ.Wumbley reports that `ash` will reproduce this message:

```
ash -c 'addr2line (nil) -e xcep_app'
```